# Replacing null info if matching id in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am pulling from multiple tables and have three union queries. I want information that is not in one row to be filled into the information from another row while still keeping a separate list of values for the month.

There is three rows for each id and essentially I want any information that is not in a row to be copied from a row with a matching id, but still keeping the three rows separate due to some pivoted monthly data that I want to keep separate for each row.

[image: Link shows what I want here]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions:

```
select max(name) over (partition by id) as name,
       max(zip) over (partition by id) as zip,
       max(type1) over (partition by id) as type1,
       id, type, "201907", "201906", "201905"
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT
    T2.MAX_NAME,
    T2.MAX_ZIP,
    T2.MAX_TYPE,
    T1.ID,
    T1.TYP1,
    T1."201907",
    T1."201906",
    T1."201905"
FROM
    TAB T1
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            MAX(NAME) MAX_NAME,
            MAX(ZIP) MAX_ZIP,
            MAX(TYPE) MAX_TYPE,
            ID
        FROM
            TAB
        GROUP BY
            ID
    ) T2 ON ( T1.ID = T2.ID );
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=706bb3cd1ad0a15f99ce29daea4bd61c)